# An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly, .net-core

based on this [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/7154)
I tried another way for loading assembly so I wrote a snippet code for loading assembly

```
  public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var name = AssemblyLoadContext.GetAssemblyName(@"C:\MainParser.Contract.dll");
            var loaded = Assembly.Load(name);
        }
    }
```

**Error Message**

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll
>
> Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'MainParser.Contract, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.

[image]

```
Microsoft .NET Core Shared Framework Host

  Version  : 1.0.1
  Build    : cee57bf6c981237d80aa1631cfe83cb9ba329f12

dotnet --version
1.0.0-preview2-003131
```

seems name variable get info from .dll file correctly but Why in loading said FileNotFound ?

Comment: Does the .dll, you know.. exist?

Comment: @ThePerplexedOne , If you see picture name variable got info from .dll so dll exists and dit not move or rename

Comment: Does that library itself have dependencies that might not be met? I feel like in a chained load the message always says the first library but the error code is for whatever library failed.

Comment: @bartonjs I used standard class of microsoft this is my snippet code on console application as simple as you see, have one dependency AssemblyLoadContext needs "System.Runtime.Loader": "4.0.0"